# Azure DevOps Variable Group not applying in Azure Function Configuration

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to leverage the Variable Group functionality in Azure DevOps.

I have created the variable group within the Release pipeline and I have associated.  However, when I release the code to the Function App in Azure; when I go to the Configuration settings in the Function app, the custom settings are not there.

Is there a step I am missing here on getting these to show up?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

UPDATE: To fix this; I needed to write the variables. This is the step I did it.

[image]

Comment: it's missing the part where you read them and update the function app

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio thanks--makes sense.  Where is a step that I should add that?

Comment: You should be using an Azure keyvault for storing secured variables, not an Azure DevOps pipeline. Your application can retrieve secrets directly from the keyvault at runtime. You're adding several additional steps and making secret management opaque and difficult for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do this using a powershell task after publishing the new code. So add a new powershell task and define it as inline:

```
$appname = "name of your function app"
$rg = "name of resource group"
$webApp = Get-AzureRmwebApp -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $appname
$webAppSettings = $webApp.SiteConfig.AppSettings
$hash = @{}
foreach ($setting in $webAppSettings) {
    $hash[$setting.Name] = $setting.Value
}
$hash['New name'] = $("pipelineVariable")
Set-AzureRMWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $appname -AppSettings $hash -Slot production
```

PS: define the deployment slot as a variable too

Comment: Thanks Thiago; although I didn't need to implement the powershell; your tip on needing to write the variable allowed me to fix it!