# How do you integrate Key Vault into an application in a secure way?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I am trying to integrate KeyVault into my Azure App service. I have a KeyVault client library embedded in my application. In order for this client library to connect to KeyVault and access stored secrets, some configurations must be available for the client to connect. There are 4 types of credential objects that the client attempts to use, in a specific order, during initialization for authentication/authorization. The first credential object it tries to use is an environment based object. This object attempts to gather 4 environment variables from the hosting system to initialize the KeyVault client. One of these variables must contain the ClientSecret of the application trying to connect to KeyVault via the client lib. The problem I am running into is this. In my azure release pipeline I am trying to set the environment variables of the deployed host appropriately for the application to use. However, it appears that the release tasks all run on the same host, until you get to the actual deployment task of the app service. Apparently this task runs on a different host? When running the hostname command on previous tasks they all returned one hostname while the hostname command added to the deployment task returned a another. I am a little stuck and having trouble finding more clarity about setting environment variables for an app service through documentation. Does anyone have any ideas? Am I going about integrating KeyVault correctly or is there something I am missing? Please let me know if clarification is needed or more information is required to assist me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Azure App Services, this is way easier. You directly [link application configuration from KeyVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references) using Managed Identities.

Sample config value will look like this:

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/ec96f02080254f109c51a1f14cdb1931)
```

This way you

1. don't have to change anything in your application code. The app reads
   secrets from KeyVault just like any other configuration
2. do not need to manage any client-side credentials to access KeyVault.

Comment: I will explore this option. Thank you.

Comment: Only downside with this is that you need the secret version in the URI. If you access Key Vault using a Managed Identity from your code, you don't need the version, just the secret name.

Comment: It is recommended practice anyway to always reference a secret by its version

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the Variables in your Pipeline and retrieve them (from Key Vault), during the release process.

PS: Your app will receive/read them as Environment Variables.

[Azure DevOps Variable Group not applying in Azure Function Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60193501/1384539)

Comment: I have imported KeyVault values into variables in the pipeline. I will consider the solutions provided in the link you added. Thank you for the help!